Failed to open /dev/ttyACM1
I'm running JS8CALL on a new PI 5, used for digital mode on a ham radio.
It works intermittently, If I swith bands or close it and reopen it I get this:
Failed to open "/dev/ttyACM1".  Need Help!

Read The Fine Documentation.
